# How to inspect the contents of a container of a pod deployed with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I run an `.NET Core 2.1` in a container. It writes logs to a file within the container. I am able to run a `docker exec bash` command to inspect the log file, locally.

This application is then deployed with `Kubernetes` to a pod with more than one container.

How can I inspect the log file within each one of these containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exec into container within pod:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it <pod name> -c <container name> bash
```

But the better approach is to make your application stream logs to stdout or stderr, so you can access it directly with:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> logs <pod name> -c <container name>
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to mention sidecar containers that for streaming logfiles, for applications that can't necessarily be modified to output to stdout/err?